# How would I mimic CanvasRenderingContext2D's arc method? - Javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I have been trying to mimic the arc method that belongs to the CanvasRenderingContext2D class for HTML5's canvas element. I have it somewhat working, but I just can't seem to wrap my head around the whole thing.

I made a [jsfiddle test environment](http://jsfiddle.net/sQpTC/2/) to make testing the function go faster, so feel free to use it.

I am trying to make this for a few of my projects that I want to port to the [IvanK library](http://lib.ivank.net/), which does not appear to support circle strokes.

Comment: just a comment, on that lib page, he says he uses WebGL to render everything, and that it works on mobile devices. I think he might be a bit confused!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [midpoint circle algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm) to draw a circle or a circle segment pixel by pixel

Comment: [This](http://jsfiddle.net/sQpTC/3/) is what I have come up with using the code from the page you directed me to. I don't know how to implement it correctly, but I think that even if I do it correctly, I will have the same problems I did before.

Comment: Yeah the problem is that you're doing lines, not pixels. The pseudocode function setPixel in the wikipedia example is supposed to fill just a single pixel. You can probably draw 1px long lines, or use getImageData and change that pixel by pixel

Comment: I could probably get it to work but I would still have the same problems when implementing the startAngle and endAngle parameters. I've been looking at it for a while now and it seems that I am having trouble understanding how the native arc function really works. It almost seems like it's flipped upside down.

Comment: So, apparently (and I've never learned it this way before), it is upside down according to [this.](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/canvas_arc.asp)

Answer (score 0):

So I just spent way too much time trying to figure this out, and I think I finally got it.
This is the function I finally came up with.

```
arcL = function( x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, anticlockwise )
{
    if ( anticlockwise )
    {
        var t = startAngle
        startAngle = endAngle
        endAngle = t
    }

    var d = Math.abs(endAngle - startAngle);
    if ( d >= Math.PI * 2 )
        endAngle = startAngle + Math.PI * 2;
    else
    {
        if ( endAngle < startAngle )
            endAngle += tau
        else
            endAngle = startAngle + d;
    }

    ctx.moveTo( x + radius * Math.cos( startAngle ), y + radius * Math.sin( startAngle) );
    for ( ; startAngle < endAngle; startAngle += 0.02 )
        ctx.lineTo( x + radius * Math.cos( startAngle ), y + radius * Math.sin( startAngle ) );
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sQpTC/7/)